# AJAX - Element / Class / Timer cleanup on replacing content

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools, destructor

As many developers will be I'm producing web based application that are using AJAX to retrieve data and HTML.

I'm new to web development and javascript but have a couple of decades experience in programming in other languages.

I'm using mootools, which is a great framework, but have been battleing with the lack of destructors in javascript or even onDestroys/ unloads for the dom elements.

I've written a number of UI classes ( mostly to learn ) and alot of them use setInterval timers to periodically get data from the WebServer and update elements on the page (mostly images from cameras).

Most issue occur when another page is requested with the menu and the content div is reloaded with new HTML and Javascript ( using Request.HTML ).  This simple replaces all the elements already in the div with the new one and runs the new scripts.  Any timers in the old scripts or old objects created will continue to run.  This was leaving me with lots of orphaned Clases, elements and timers.

I've been reading more on the  mootools site and have realized a number of mistakes I've been making and have started to correct alot of the issues. The biggest of which was not using Element.store and Element.retrieve instead of linking my classes directly to the Elements.

I've already found that the contents of the div being reloaded need to be freed by calling destroy on all its child elements before calling the Request.HTML but that will not remove (clear) any timers that are running.

So I've done a JSFiddle here [deinitialize classes](http://jsfiddle.net/FmkQy/5/) to show what i've been trying, its appears to work fine but the following and what i want to know is,

- Is it a good idea?
- are there any other issues I might have missed?
- can you see any problem with this type of implementation ?
- or am I reinventing the wheel and missed
  something?

Explanation

When the class is initialized it stores itself with the element.

It also appendes (makes if necessary) itself into an AssocClasses array also stored with the element.

I've created a ClearElement function that is called whenever the contents of an element are to be replace with and AJAX call or other method, which gets all elements within the div and if they have and AssocClasses array attached, calls the deinitialize on each of the Classes in the array, then it calls destroy on each of its direct children to free the elements/storage.

Any information, pointers etc would be most greatfully recieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Most issue occur when another page is requested with the menu and the content div is reloaded with new HTML and Javascript ( using Request.HTML ). This simple replaces all the elements already in the div with the new one and runs the new scripts. Any timers in the old scripts or old objects created will continue to run. This was leaving me with lots of orphaned Clases, elements and timers.
```

I would rethink your timer storage and use of evalScripts in your ajax calls.

Keep these outside of your AJAX requests. When doing peer code reviews rarely have I seen an instance where these were needed and could be done in a better way.

Maybe on the link that is clicked have it trigger a callback function on Complete or onSuccess

Without seeing your exact code it will be hard to advise further.

Comment: Thankyou Tim for responding, i know I've not given much code to go on, I'll try to put something together on the web but that will be some time off. I was thinking of using Assets to dynamically load tthe JS and even CSS for each app will make a manager to ensure I only add them once.  I will carry on using firebug to see how other site are doing thing and reading formus, I'll probably eventually stop trying to get get everything looking more like the code I'm use too (Delphi) and realise how it should be done.  BTW I've bookmarked your blog.

Comment: Assets is a very powerful class I use it for instances like this often. In terms of the JS files loaded for each app (or module or page, depending on what your coding) I typically try to encapsulate all vars and functions inside an object to avoid namespace collisions with other dynamically loaded custom scripts. In regards to the blog, In the next few weeks it will be relaunched with a new responsive design as well as about 15 Classes I have written with full demos and docs and githiub links.